# How to prove that the weak topology is strictly weaker than the norm topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $H$  be a Hilbert space. I read that the weak topology is weaker than the norm topology but I couldn't work out how to prove it. It is clear to me that by definition the weak topology is at least as weak as the norm topology (since the norm topology also makes all continuous functionals continuous).

> But how to prove that it is strictly weaker?

Comment: Won't you at least need to assume that $H$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: @kahen Thank you! I will delete it. It is true that I mentioned just $l^2$, but probably you know, that this is actually the only infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. I could replace ${\mathbb N}$ by any index set and that would cover all Hilbert spaces - the idea of the proof would be the same. About the question: it is mentioned that student knows that weak topology is weaker than the norm topology, the question was to see that it is strictly weaker. I wanted to point out that there are nets which converge in one topoly but not in the other - hence the topologies are different.

Comment: Hint: if $H$ has finite dimension, then the weak topology and the norm topology are the same, as kahen mentioned. If $H$ has infinite dimension, then every open set in the weak topology is unbouneded (i.e. contains elements of arbitrarily large norm). However, open norm-balls (i.e. $\{x \in H\ |\ \|x-y\| < \epsilon \}$) are bounded. This means that open norm-balls are not open in the weak topology.

Answer (score 11):

To show that the weak topology is strictly weaker, you need a norm-open set that is not weakly open. The unit ball $B=\{x:\|x\|<1\}$ is such a set. Indeed, suppose it is weakly open. By the definition of the weak topology, there exists a finite set of functionals $f_1,\dots,f_n$ such that 
$$
\{x: |f_k(x)|<1 \text{ for }k=1,\dots,n\} \subset B
$$
But from  any $n+1$ linearly independent elements $x_1,\dots,x_{n+1} \in X$ you can make a nonzero linear combination $x_0$ such that $f_k(x_0)=0$ for all $k=1,\dots,n$. (Think of the rank of the matrix $(f_i(x_j))$.) It follows that $tx_0\in B$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, which is impossible.